# Error de función indefinida

Tags: php

El siguiente código me tira este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add() in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\crearnoticia.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\crearnoticia.php on line 17

```php
<?php
include_once 'cone.php';
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $noticiaql = "INSERT INTO um_not (um_titulo, um_desccorta, um_desclarga, um_imgchica, um_imggrande, um_fecha, um_um, um_destacada, um_genero, um_relacionadas, um_tags) 
    VALUES(:titulo, :desccorta, :desclarga, :imgchica, :imggrande, :fecha, :um, :destacada, :genero, :relacionadas, :tags)";
    $arrayParameters = array(':titulo' => $_POST['titulo'],
                             ':desccorta' => $_POST['desccorta'],
                             ':desclarga' => $_POST['desclarga'],
                             ':imgchica' => $_POST['imgchica'],
                             ':fecha' => $_POST['fecha'],
                             ':um' => $_POST['um'],
                             ':destacada' => $_POST['destacada'],
                             ':genero' => $_POST['genero'],
                             ':relacionadas' => $_POST['relacionadas'],
                             ':tags' => $_POST['tags']);
    $totalsql=add($noticiaql, $arrayParameters);
    if ($totalsql >0){echo "salió bien.";}
    else{echo "salió mal.";}
    function add($noticiaql, $arrayParameters){
        $stmt=$con->prepare($noticiasql);
        $insert=$stmt->execute($arrayParameters);
        $totalsql = ($insert) ? $stmt->rowCount() : 0;
        return $totalsql;
    }
} 
?>
```

¿Alguien podría ofrecerme su ayuda?

Edición:
crearnoticia.php

```php
<?php
    $titulo      = ( !empty($_POST['titulo']) )       ? $_POST['titulo']       : NULL;
    $desccorta   = ( !empty($_POST['desccorta']) )    ? $_POST['desccorta']    : NULL;
    $desclarga   = ( !empty($_POST['desclarga']) )    ? $_POST['desclarga']    : NULL;
    $imgchica    = ( !empty($_POST['imgchica']) )     ? $_POST['imgchica']     : NULL;
    $imggrande   = ( !empty($_POST['imggrande']) )    ? $_POST['imggrande']    : NULL;
    $fecha       = ( !empty($_POST['fecha']) )        ? $_POST['fecha']        : NULL;
    $um          = ( !empty($_POST['um']) )           ? $_POST['um']           : NULL;
    $destacada   = ( !empty($_POST['destacada']) )    ? $_POST['destacada']    : NULL;
    $genero      = ( !empty($_POST['genero']) )       ? $_POST['genero']       : NULL;
    $relacionadas= ( !empty($_POST['relacionadas']) ) ? $_POST['relacionadas'] : NULL;
    $tags        = ( !empty($_POST['tags']) )         ? $_POST['tags']         : NULL;
    if( $titulo && $desccorta && $desclarga && $imgchica && $imggrande && $fecha && $um && $destacada && $genero && $relacionadas && $tags ){
        include_once 'cone.php';
        if ($db) {
            $noticiasql = "INSERT INTO um_not 
                              ( 
                                um_titulo, 
                                um_desccorta, 
                                um_desclarga, 
                                um_imgchica, 
                                um_imggrande, 
                                um_fecha, 
                                um_um, 
                                um_destacada, 
                                um_genero, 
                                um_relacionadas, 
                                um_tags
                              ) 
                              VALUES 
                              (
                                :titulo, 
                                :desccorta, 
                                :desclarga, 
                                :imgchica, 
                                :imggrande, 
                                :fecha, 
                                :um, 
                                :destacada, 
                                :genero, 
                                :relacionadas, 
                                :tags
                              )";
            $arrParams = array(
                                ':titulo' => $titulo,
                                ':desccorta' => $desccorta,
                                ':desclarga' => $desclarga,
                                ':imgchica' => $imgchica,
                                ':imggrande' => $imggrande,
                                ':fecha' => $fecha,
                                ':um' => $um,
                                ':destacada' => $destacada,
                                ':genero' => $genero,
                                ':relacionadas' => $relacionadas,
                                ':tags' => $tags
                                );
            $stmt=$db->prepare($noticiasql);
            if  ($stmt && $stmt->execute($arrParams) ) {
                $msgOut="¡Todo bien! Filas insertadas: ".$stmt->rowCount();     
            } else {
                $msgOut="Hubo un error: ".$db->errorInfo()[2];
            }
        } else {
            $msgOut="La conexión es nula";
        }
    } else {
        $msgOut="Las variables son nulas, revise el POST";
    }
    echo $msgOut;   
?>
```

cone.php

```php
<?php
    try {$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=news;charset=utf8mb4','root','theboss10');}
    catch(PDOException $ex){echo "algo salió mal.";}
?>
```

Comment: public es un modificador de acceso a métodos y atributos, dentro del paradigma de la POO, por el contrario yo no veo que tengas tu código dentro de una clase, por lo cual ese `public` no tiene sentido de existir ahi

Comment: Paso a editar...

Comment: Me da ese error que actualicé...

Comment: por que usar `$this->` es aplicable propiedades que estan dentro del alcance de la misma clase que las contiene, pero volvemos a lo mismo si no tienes una clase, hacer uso de eso es incorrecto

Comment: Ese código es todo lo que tengo, más el html.

Comment: no uses `$this->varName` por que no estas haciendo poo, en su lugar solo has esto `$varName`

Comment: He arreglado eso y ahora me salta el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add() in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\crearnoticia.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\crearnoticia.php on line 17

Comment: actualiza la pregunta completa, modificando el contenido y añadiendo este error que me acabas de indicar

Comment: no puedes invocar a la función `add` antes de declararla, justo en esa línea 17 donde haces esto `$totalsql=add($noticiaql, $arrayParameters);` dicha función aún no existe pues tu la declaras con toda su estructra líneas mas abajo

Comment: ¿Entonces cuándo debería llamarla?

Comment: ok @Morderisk te haré una propuesta de solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas en tu código:

1. No le veo ningún sentido a tu función `add`. No aporta nada y todo tu código se puede ejecutar en un solo contexto. Además, hay que hacer una serie de evaluaciones sobre la preparación y ejecución de la consulta si quieres escribir un código controlado. Pasar de repente a otra función sin ninguna justificación lo único que hace es complicarlo todo.
2. Tampoco tiene demasiada utilidad preguntar por el REQUEST METHOD  ... ¿?  El interés debe centrarse más bien sobre los datos que vas a manejar. En mi código yo hago una evaluación de cada dato con un ternario, guardo el contenido en una variable y luego evalúo los datos en sí que es lo que interesa. Si algún dato esencial es nulo, no lanzo la inserción, porque fallaría al estarle pasando un dato `NULL`.
3. Voy a preguntar hasta por la conexión. No se puede uno fiar de nada y la conexión puede ser nula. De paso, hago el `include` únicamente cuando esté seguro de que voy a necesitar la conexión, no antes.
4. Observa que he identado la instrucción SQL. Que no te parezca largo. Con el código escrito así podrás comparar fácilmente si no hay incompatibilidad entre las columnas y los valores. Y te permitirá darte cuenta si tienes errores en el array de parámetros. **De hecho, tienes un error en el array de parámetros, ¡te faltaba una columna!**. Con el código así identado te das cuenta casi de inmediato.
5. El resto del código consiste en evaluar tanto el `prepare` como el `execute` y determinar el estado del código en base a un posible error o a la cantidad de filas insertadas.

El código sería este aplicando todo lo dicho anteriormente. Prueba y dime cómo te ha ido:

```
<?php 
    /*
        Usaremos ternarios para recuperar los valores del POST
        y asignarlos a variables o asignar NULL si vinieran vacíos
    */
    $titulo      = ( !empty($_POST['titulo']) )       ? $_POST['titulo']       : NULL;
    $desccorta   = ( !empty($_POST['desccorta']) )    ? $_POST['desccorta']    : NULL;
    $desclarga   = ( !empty($_POST['desclarga']) )    ? $_POST['desclarga']    : NULL;
    $imgchica    = ( !empty($_POST['imgchica']) )     ? $_POST['imgchica']     : NULL;
    $fecha       = ( !empty($_POST['fecha']) )        ? $_POST['fecha']        : NULL;
    $um          = ( !empty($_POST['um']) )           ? $_POST['um']           : NULL;
    $destacada   = ( !empty($_POST['destacada']) )    ? $_POST['destacada']    : NULL;
    $genero      = ( !empty($_POST['genero']) )       ? $_POST['genero']       : NULL;
    $relacionadas= ( !empty($_POST['relacionadas']) ) ? $_POST['relacionadas'] : NULL;
    $tags        = ( !empty($_POST['tags']) )         ? $_POST['tags']         : NULL;

    /*
        Incluir en este if todos los valores que no pueden ser NULL
        Aquí los he puesto todos por precaución
    */
    if( $titulo && $desccorta && $desclarga && $imgchica && $fecha && $um && $destacada && $genero && $relacionadas && $tags ){
        include_once 'cone.php';
        if ($con) {
            $noticiaql = "INSERT INTO um_not 
                              ( 
                                um_titulo, 
                                um_desccorta, 
                                um_desclarga, 
                                um_imgchica, 
                                um_imggrande, 
                                um_fecha, 
                                um_um, 
                                um_destacada, 
                                um_genero, 
                                um_relacionadas, 
                                um_tags
                              ) 
                              VALUES 
                              (
                                :titulo, 
                                :desccorta, 
                                :desclarga, 
                                :imgchica, 
                                :imggrande, 
                                :fecha, 
                                :um, 
                                :destacada, 
                                :genero, 
                                :relacionadas, 
                                :tags
                              )";
            $arrParams = array(
                                ':titulo' => $titulo,
                                ':desccorta' => $desccorta,
                                ':desclarga' => $desclarga,
                                ':imgchica' => $imgchica,
                                ':imggrande' => $imggrande,
                                ':fecha' => $fecha,
                                ':um' => $um,
                                ':destacada' => $destacada,
                                ':genero' => $genero,
                                ':relacionadas' => $relacionadas,
                                ':tags' => $tags
                                );
            $stmt=$con->prepare($noticiasql);
            if  ($stmt && $stmt->execute($arrParams) ) {
                $msgOut="¡Todo bien! Filas insertadas: ".$stmt->rowCount();     
            } else {
                $msgOut="Hubo un error: ".$stmt->errorInfo()[2];
            }
        } else {
            $msgOut="La conexión es nula";
        }
    } else {
        $msgOut="Las variables son nulas, revise el POST";
    }
    echo $msgOut;   
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo() in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\crearnoticia.php:70 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\crearnoticia.php on line 70

Comment: @Morderisk entonces tú estás usando mysqli, no PDO. El código que tienes, y la forma de pasar los parámetros son propios de PDO. En mysqli los parámetros no se pasan en array, sino con  `bind_param`. Al ver ese estilo pensé que usabas PDO. Puedes si quieras pasarte a PDO o bien indicarme que quieres seguir con mysqli, en cuyo caso hay que cambiar considerablemente el código.

Comment: <?php
$hostsql = 'localhost';
$usersql = 'root';
$passsql = 'theboss10';
$dbsql = 'news';
$con =($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($hostsql, $usersql, $passsql))or die ('Ha fallado la conexión: '.((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
<?

Comment: <?php
$dbname='news';
$user='root';
$password='theboss10';
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname";
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?> _Intenté con el mysqli y ese intento de conexión con PDO_

Comment: No mezcles @Morderisk. Debes decidirte si quieres usar PDO o MySQLi (yo recomiendo PDO). Y te aconsejo que crees una clase para gestionar la conexión, así la usas cada vez que necesites conectarte. Si te interesa te paso el enlace de un modelo de clase de conexión.

Comment: He usado la conexión PDO, y sin embargo siempre me tira "Hubo un error: "

Comment: ¿Y no muestra el error?  ¿Cómo te conectas a PDO? @Morderisk

Comment: No muestra nada, sólo el texto ese. Me conecto con: <?php
 try {$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=news;charset=utf8mb4','root','theboss10');}
 catch(PDOException $ex){echo "algo salió mal.";}
?>

Comment: @Morderisk ¿podrías por favor editar tu pregunta, poniendo al final de la misma cómo tienes el código actualmente? No borres lo que ya ahí, sólo agrega tu código actual al final como una edición, así podré revisarlo.

Comment: @Morderisk pon la captura del error así: `$msgOut="Hubo un error: ".$stmt->errorInfo()[2];`, cambia `$db` por `$stmt`, no sea que haya algún error en tus nombres de tabla o columnas. Ahí te capturará el error.

Comment: Era un error de tipeo por lo que veo, primero que nada, el nombre de la tabla era um.not y yo intentaba con um_not, luego cambié a um.not el intento y se ve que no reconoce los puntos, así que lo puse finalmente a todo con um_not. Gracias por todas las respuestas. El request method era porque al estar todo en una misma página se envía nada más cargar.

Comment: @Morderisk eso de que se envíe nada más cargar lo puedes controlar con Ajax, poniendo un botón de envío de los datos y poniendo `preventDefault`. Aquí hay varios ejemplos de eso. El uso de ternarios impedirá cualquier cosa si los datos están vacíos, pero no es bueno tener un código que se envía él sólo, debes controlar eso. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto, ¡finalmente!

Answer (score 1):

> El error que te sale es por que la función `add()` la estas invocando
>   y usando líneas arriba, en la 17 donde aún no existe su declaración o
>   cuerpo de la misma, entonces el error te indica estas usando una
>   función que justo aqui en la línea 17 no existe sino unas líneas abajo

Yo veo que usas la función `add` con la única finalidad de procesar la consulta pasándole como argumentos el array de los valores y la consulta en si, te propongo esta lógica para poder realizar lo mismo, sistituyendo tus condicionales de si se ejecuta o si no, por el uso de un `try/catch`

Pasamos el array asociativo que tienes declarado con las variables, dentro del método `execute()`

```
include_once 'cone.php';
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    try{
        $noticiaql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO um_not (um_titulo, um_desccorta, 
                                    um_desclarga, um_imgchica, um_imggrande, 
                                    um_fecha, um_um, um_destacada, um_genero, 
                                    um_relacionadas, um_tags) 
                                    VALUES(:titulo, :desccorta, :desclarga, 
                                    :imgchica, :imggrande, :fecha, :um, 
                                    :destacada, :genero, :relacionadas, :tags)");

    $noticiaql->execute(array(':titulo' => $_POST['titulo'],
                             ':desccorta' => $_POST['desccorta'],
                             ':desclarga' => $_POST['desclarga'],
                             ':imgchica' => $_POST['imgchica'],
                             ':fecha' => $_POST['fecha'],
                             ':um' => $_POST['um'],
                             ':destacada' => $_POST['destacada'],
                             ':genero' => $_POST['genero'],
                             ':relacionadas' => $_POST['relacionadas'],
                             ':tags' => $_POST['tags']));
    }catch(PDOException $exception){
        return $exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me tira este error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\crearnoticia.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\crearnoticia.php on line 14